# DotNetNuke - deleted HTML Pro module - Need to recover the data

Tags: dotnetnuke

I accidentally uninstalled the DotNetNuke HTML Pro Module and it deleted the tables and all the data I had created for that module. Is there a way I can recover this data and the tables?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to restore the latest backup of your database that contains the table structure and data you're looking for.  If you don't have a backup, you're unfortunately out of luck.